# docker-compose: seeing all the services together from command line

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I have the following yml file, the services are created correctly, but when installing wordpress I cannot logon to mysql and I need to understand why.

I'm totally new to docker, I'd need to see all the services together from command line (bash), now I'm running a command like

`$ sudo docker exec -ti 4295b34c014a /bin/bash`

but I get a login to a specific service, how can I view wordpress and mysql together from cli?

yml file (from [here](https://medium.com/@truthseekersio/how-to-setup-wordpress-in-docker-1abae61c7dc)):

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
    db:
        image: mysql
        volumes:
            - 'wptut:/var/lib/mysql'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlpassword
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        ports:
            - '81:80'
volumes:
    wptut: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by viewing them together, but in order to check if they are running you can use `docker ps` and if you want to see the logs after you `docker-compose up -d` use `docker-compose logs -f`. You should also make sure in WordPress you are referencing your MySQL database properly. For hostname, you should probably use `db` instead of `localhost`

Comment: The error was referring to the host as localhost, db was the correct host, thank you!

Comment: however, seeing all the services together meant seeing the files installed by the services and the running processes together

Answer (score 1):

Each service is running in a separate container. If you want log access, `docker-compose up` should stream logs from all three by default. If you detached from the `docker-compose up` session I think `docker-compose logs -f` should also combine log output of all services. `docker-compose exec` attaches to a running container, you can only do that to one container at a time. At the very least you can run `docker-compose exec wordpress` or another service name as a convenience over the direct docker command you have above. `docker-compose logs -f wordpress` also works for a one-off.